# Multiplying a value with Ampscipt

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'd like to multiply the quantity value I have stored in my DE by 1.25.
The DE field is set to number. I've named the variable `@Pens`.
I created another variable `@PensCost` to store the value of `@Pens x 1.25`.

I've tried:

```
SET @PensCost = Multiply(@Pens, 1.25)
```

but I get an error message:

> Multiply Parameter Name: Value1 Parameter Ordinal: 1 Parameter Type: Numeric Submitted." What am I doing wrong?

I've used this same format for other products and it's working fine. When I use `%%=v(@Pens)=%%` it returns the quantity number so I know my variable does have data.

More detailed code:

```
%%[ 
VAR @Pens, @PensCost
SET @Pens = AttributeValue("PAPERMATE PENS BLUE FINE POINT 15 ct")
SET @PensCost = Multiply(@Pens, 1.25) 
]%%
%%=v(@PensCost)=%%
```

Comment: From a quick glance, it should work, however, I would love to see the full code where you're referencing the @Pens variable to the DE field. cheers

Comment: Did you verify if there was the possibility of a null value? If there is no condition to check that, if `@Pens` is ever null, it will toss an error on the Multiply.

Comment: Thanks but I set the default value of the field to 0. I was able to read the quantity when I wrote %%=v(@Pens)=%% but the multiply function wasn't working. Not sure why just changing the DE field name allowed it to worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my solve for anyone else dealing with the same issue. Even though the data extension field was set to Number and I was able to access the value with `%%=v(@Pens)=%%` I was getting errors on any math function.

All I did was change the field name in the DE to `PAPERMATE PENS BLUE 15ct` and update

```
SET @Pens = AttributeValue("PAPERMATE PENS BLUE 15ct")
```

It's working now.